# Expansion about a background classical solution to the Kaluza-Klein five-dimensional field equations

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, kaluza-klein

This is a paper I am reading [Five-dimensional quantum gravity and the residual length](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.34.3666) by Roberto Balbinot and Antonio Barletta.
I am not able to figure out how he got the expressions in equations 2.11-2.14.
Please help.